# Jquery Undo Animation of Image by Click (website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, interactive

For my school project I am making a website that displays a wall full of sneakers and I want to make it interactive.[Picture of the Wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRCV1.jpg)

I have a background image, and all the shoe's are separate image's.

So what i've done now is this :

```
<script>
$('.schoen').click(function() {
var tar = $(this)
tar.fadeIn().animate({
top: "10%",
left: "30%",
height: '+=570px',
width: '+=374px',
},
{duration: 'slow', queue: false}, function() { });
})
</script>
```

*This is making the shoe bigger and it places it in the middle when you click it .*

In my HTML code i used this for the Shoe.

```
<div id="S-222" class="schoen"><img src="schoenenuitgeknipt\airmax97gr.png"width="187,5" height="262,5"></div>
```

I use the ID in css to place them

**My Question is: How do I make it go back to it's original position and size when I click it again.**

I'm really stuck here for quite a while now, been searching but couldn't find an good answer.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me out!

Comment: Very sorry for that still appreciate the effort that you putted in to give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reverse the animation on the last shoe when another one is clicked

```
<script>
    var lastShoe = null,
        lastShoeTop, lastShoeLeft, lastShoeWidth, lastShoeHeight;
    $('.schoen').click(function() {
        var tar = $(this)
        if (lastShoe != null) {
            lastShoe.fadeOut().animate({
                top: lastShoeTop,
                left: lastShoeLeft,
                height: lastShoeWidth,
                width: lastShoeHeight,
            }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                queue: false
            });
        }
        if (!tar.is(lastShoe)) {
            lastShoe = tar;
            lastShoeTop = lastShoe.position().top;
            lastShoeLeft = lastShoe.position().left;
            lastShoeWidth = lastShoe.width();
            lastShoeHeight = lastShoe.height();
            tar.fadeIn().animate({
                top: "10%",
                left: "30%",
                height: '+=570px',
                width: '+=374px',
            }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                queue: false
            });
        } else {
            lastShoe = null;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also a few comments:

- HTML5 discourages usage of width and height attributes and suggest
  using CSS instead
- You can't set a width of 187,5 pixels because pixels have to be whole numbers

Comment: It make's all the shoes dissapear in the top left corner, I'm not to good at this so i don't know where to place your code -.-' .

Comment: Your question has insufficient info to be answered. It seems like you are using absolute positioning, so there is no clean way to make it. The only thing you can do is remember the shoe positioning before it was clicked and reversing it when another is clicked. Give me some time to edit my answer.

Comment: You are correct, in my css i use position:Absolute.
And in CSS I call the ID and position them with top:-5% left: 53% etc.

Comment: This is a bad approach to this kind of problem. You have to try to structure your code and use relative positioning. Check my edit.

Comment: It is working when i click another shoe it get's back in position but it is deformed. Not the original size, I appreciate the time you took the help me out anyways. But what I really need is to click the same shoe again to make it go back in original position. I will try and play with the positioning to make it relative.

Comment: answer edited and should return the current shoe. Nothing I can do about the deformation with the current info.

Comment: Andrey your the best. It works like a charm now i don't know how but it works, still have the deformation but i will fix that.

Comment: in my css i have done this with my image:
img{
width: 75%;
height:75%;
}

Comment: If you set the width and height from the HTML attributes that shouldn't change a thing